# Adding centralized configuration to our servers

Tags: configuration, distributed

As our systems grow, there are more and more servers and services (different types and multiple instances of the same type that require minor config changes). We are looking for a "cetralized configuration" solution, preferably existing and nothing we need to develop from scrtach.
The idea is something like, service goes up, it knows a single piece of data (its type+location+version+serviceID or something like that) and contacts some central service that will give it its proper config (file, object or whatever).
If the service that goes online can't find the config service it will either use a cached config or refuse to initialize (behavior should probably be specified in the startup parameters it's getting from whom or whatever is bringing it online)
The config service should be highly avaiable i.e. a cluster of servers (ZooKeeper keeps sounding like a perfect candidate)
The service should preferably support the concept of inheritence, allowing a global configuration file for the type of service and then specific overrides or extensions for each instance of the service by its ID. Also, it should support something like config versioning, allowing to keep different configurations of the same service type for different versions since we want to rely more on more on side by side rollout of services.
The other side of the equation is that there is a config admin tool that connects to the same centralized config service, and can review and update all the configurations based on the requirements above.

I know that if I modify the core requirement from serivce pulling config data to having the data pushed to it I can use something like puppet or chef to manage everything. I have to be honest, I have little experience with these two systems (our IT team has more), but from my investigations I can say it seemed they are NOT the right tools for this job.

Are there any systems similar to the one I describe above that anyone has integrated with?

Answer (score 2):

I've only had experience with home grown solutions so my answer may not solve your issue but may help someone else.  We've utilized web servers and SVN robots quite successfully for configuration management.   This solution would not mean that you would have to "develop from scratch" but is not a turn-key solution either.

We had multiple web-servers each refreshing its configurations from a SVN repository at a synchronized minute basis.  The clients would make requests of the servers with the `/type=...&location=...&version=...` type of HTTP arguments.  Those values could then be used in the views when necessary to customize the configurations.  We did this both with Spring XML files that were being reloaded live and standard `field=value` property files.

Our system was pull only although we could trigger a pull via JMX If necessary.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

[Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) (of which I am the maintainer) can provide you with most of the capabilities you are looking for out-of-the-box, and I suspect you could easily build the remaining capabilities on top of it.

Read Chapters 2 and 3 of the "Getting Started" manual to get a feel for Config4*'s capabilities (don't worry, they are very short chapters). Doing that should help you decide how well Config4* meets your needs.

You can find links to PDF and HTML versions of the manuals near the end of the main page of the [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) website.